# MySQL query: retrieve some rows based on keys in another table

Tags: mysql

I'm new at MySQL, so I will use an example to expose my problem...

I have two tables:

**Table1:**

```
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| id | a1  | b1  | c1  | d1  |
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  1 | ... | ... | ... | ... |
|  2 | ... | ... | ... | ... |
|  3 | ... | ... | ... | ... |
|  4 | ... | ... | ... | ... |
|  5 | ... | ... | ... | ... |
|  6 | ... | ... | ... | ... |
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

**Table2:**

```
+----+-----+-----+-----+---------------+
| id | a2  | b2  | c2  | table1_row_id |
+----+-----+-----+-----+---------------+
|  1 | ... | ... | ... | ...           |
|  2 | ... | ... | ... | 4             |
|  3 | ... | ... | ... | ...           |
+----+-----+-----+-----+---------------+
```

Table2 column `table1_row_id` is the key for table1.

Which kind of query should I use to retrieve table1 data that is not referenced in `table2.table1_row_id` column?

For instance, for the above tables, the query should return a table like:

```
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| id | a1  | b1  | c1  | d1  |
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  1 | ... | ... | ... | ... |
|  2 | ... | ... | ... | ... |
|  3 | ... | ... | ... | ... |
|  5 | ... | ... | ... | ... |
|  6 | ... | ... | ... | ... |
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Probably this is simple, but I don't know how should I do yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t1.a1, t1.b1, t1.c1, t1.d1
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t2.table1_row_id = t1.id
where t2.id is null
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1 
WHERE 
    `id` NOT IN (SELECT `table1_row_id` 
                 FROM t2 
                 WHERE
                     `table1_row_id` IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Normal that you can't get any rows, the subquery will return null values which will prevent main query to return rows. And also if subtable is big mysql has very poor performance with this method.  By excluding null records from subquery this will do the job. `(SELECT table1_row_id FROM table2 where table1_row_id is not null)`